# TreeView Alignment

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

i have a TreeView in my application . I want to display the nodes like following

[image]

But the String `Sample Title One0` May vary. But the alignment of Raj remains same like in the image. How can i achieve this.

I tried `myString.PadRight(100-string.length, ' ')` But the alignment is scattered.
If any other solution is there please share..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't done this already, you will need to set TreeView to use a non-proportional font like *Consolas*, instead of the default *Sans Serif*.